# How to obtain a list of branches which are only direct ancestors of the current branch?

Tags: git

Let's say you have this list of branches in a git repository:

```
* master
|
| * b2
|/
* b1
|
* b
// etc
```

I know that technically branches are only symbolic references in the DAG that is the commit graph.

If I am on the master branch here, is there a command to obtain a list of branches which are only direct ancestors of master? In the above, that would mean b1 and b, but not b2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
git branch --merged master
```

to show all branches which are completely merged into master, i.e., where the head of that branch appears in the history of `master`.

Comment: Yup, that's it! Thanks!